# Backup automatically to a hard drive

Tags: hardware

Is there a way to automatically save my blender files to my external hard drive when I work from my desktop?

Like saving it to multiple file paths. Someone on the blender community did create an add on, however it looks like it's only for rendered files. I'm looking to back up the entire project every time that I save. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I simply use Google Drive desktop app to designate a folder on my hard drive to mirror to Google Drive anytime a change is made.

[image]

What's nice about it is that it's just copying a folder on your hard drive, so you can access and use the files as normal and everything else is taken care of in the background.  You can install the app on multiple computers to make sure that your project repository is available on any machine.

Google Drive has file version history as well, if you log in to Drive on the web you can right click on a file and select Manage Previous Versions to restore something you accidentally saved over or deleted.

[image]

As we all know, data isn't real until it exists in three places, so I still use an external drive as 'cold storage'.  I just use regular file copy procedures to do a monthly backup and then disconnect the drive.

You could also use OneDrive or DropBox or a NAS or any featureful file storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general software recommendation question, I believe, but one thinks it may be migrated in the future.

I'm familiar with one specific program known as [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/) which is for Windows (multiple versions) that can be configured to monitor/check specific locations. When a change is made to that/those locations, the files are then copied/synchronized with the configured destination.

I've used this specific function to prevent data loss for a client, which worked well. The program can also be configured to respond only to a specific device, which means you can exempt a different drive from storing the synchronized files, or alternatively, use multiple drives.

The free version will work until you've performed an undetermined number of backups/synchronizing actions at which point it will request payment. The cost is relative low for such a useful, powerful program.

There may be other similar types of programs available.